# Android adb server makes Ubuntu desktop stutter

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, android, adb

My environment is Ubuntu 20.04, NVidia driver 470.103.01 (recommended), and Android SDK 33

When I start adb server by running some adb commands, the UI, mouse and other things starts to lag and stutter, and only terminal remains responsive.

You can see the kind of lags I'm talking about on [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YSdN9WtYQU). Note that even when the cursor is lagging the terminal still works smoothly, not only the built-in terminal, but also Guake terminal. The task manager doesn't seem to register any spikes neither on CPU nor on memory usage.

Do you have any idea of how to debug or fix this issue?

Comment: If you're on 20.04.2, you've not applied security fixes or patches since 2021?  Are you sure?  If you look [here](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/) you'll see the 20.04.3 ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded to it in the weeks before that, and a fully upgraded system has reported much later since then. If you're using Ubuntu (inc. Xubuntu) you should apply fixes asap & I hope your system is off-line. Are you using Ubuntu/Xubuntu?

Comment: Reader's note: also posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250105/44325

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for warning, and yes I'm on 20.04.2, will update it as soon as I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up connecting the mouse using USB dongle (no stuttering in this case) instead of builtin bluetooth. Not a solution to initial problem, but anyway this is a note for somebody who face similar issues